# Make contenteditable for a specific table span using JS onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a simple table where I'm trying to allow for the field value to be made contenteditable after pressing the edit button that I am printing next to each value:

```
 <table>  
 <tr>  
 <th>Variable A</th>  
 <th>Variable B</th>  
 <th>Variable C</th>  
 <tr>  
 <td><span id="field">Value A</span> <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button></td>  
 <td><span id="field">Value B</span> <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button></td>  
 <td><span id="field">Value C</span> <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button></td>   </tr> 
 </table>
```

I use the following jQuery upon clicking the Edit button

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("body").on('click', '.result', function() {
         var update = $(this).closest('td');
         document.getElementById('field').contentEditable = true;
         update.append('<button class=\"result\">Save</button></td>');
         $(this).remove();
    });
  });
```

Unfortunately when I click "Edit" button, only the first field (Value A) becomes editable.. I think this is because

```
 document.getElementById('field').contentEditable = true;
```

Is only updating the first instance of the id='field'

But I'm trying to make it only update the field next to where I pressed the button. So if I click the 3rd Edit button, it should make the Value C field be editable. Instead it only does Value A.

I realize that I need to make it specific to that span.. But not finding a solution. I tried:

```
$(this).closest('.field').contentEditable = true;
```

But if I do this then no spans become editable. I know this might be an easy question but I've tried all sorts of options to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` to select the span previous to `button`, and the id's should always be unique, so I changed the id `field` to `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, and I've replaced the `update.contentEditable = true;` with `update[0].contentEditable = true;`:

```js
$("body").on('click', '.result', function() {
   var update = $(this).prev('span');
   var td = $(this).closest('td');
   update[0].contentEditable = true;
   td.append('<button class=\"result\">Save</button></td>');
   $(this).remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Variable A</th>
    <th>Variable B</th>
    <th>Variable C</th>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="field_1">Value A</span> 
        <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button>
      </td>
      <td><span id="field_2">Value B</span> 
        <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button>
      </td>
      <td><span id="field_3">Value C</span> 
        <button type="button" class="result">EDIT</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am printing the table from PHP loop (coming from an SQL table).. so I didn't want to complicate and print each span with a new id name.. is there an alternative to having the spans with the unique ids? Perhaps I was overthinking and don't need spans?

Comment: You can use the key from the array on the id, like `<span id="field_<?php echo $key; ?>">Value A</span> `. Also, see my updated answer, I've used `.prev()` instead of `.find()`, and replaced `.contentEditable = true;` with `attr('contenteditable', 'true');`

Comment: @DanielC, and also, replace the `$key` with the ids from the database. Is that what you need?

Comment: thank you, I got the spans working now, but in your code it is letting even the button text be edited.. I just want the value of the span to be editable. not also the button text (like Save and Edit)

Comment: @DanielC, that's because I was appending the save button  to the span instead of the td. Check my updated answer. Is now ok?

Comment: @DanielC, awesome. I'm glad. Happy to help.